# Class Temporary Datastore, Python

Tags: python

I am having problem doing data storage and retrieval.

The essence of what I want to do is create Box A and Box B

Each box has a different description and a list of items in them and they are accessed by a Box_handler.

Basically:

```
class Box_Handler(object):
    def __init__(self,which_box):
        self.which_box = which_box
    def call_box(self):
        if self.which_box == 'A':
            self.contents = Box_A().load()
        elif self.which_box == 'B':
            self.contents = Box_B().load()
        print(self.contents)

class Box_A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = ['banana,apple,pear']

    def box_store(self):
        self.contents = self.contents+['guava']

    def load(self):
        return self.contents

class Box_B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = ['orange,fig,grape']

    def box_store(self):
        self.contents = self.contents+['guava']

    def load(self):
        return self.contents

A = Box_A()
B = Box_B()
A.box_store()
B.box_store()
Box_Handler('A').call_box()
Box_Handler('B').call_box()
```

It doesn't print guava because each time the class runs, it fires **init**, so I was thinking of putting in an **initialiser** that only ever runs once, but I run into the same issue of needing a variable to activate the **initialiser**

Does anyone have a work-about ?
I heard of pickle but if I have a thousand boxes, I need a thousand files ??!

Sorry if it's too easy, but I can't seem to find the simplest method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Box_Handler`'s `call_box`, you are creating new objects every time and you are not adding `guava` by calling `box_store`. To fix this, you can change `call_box` like this

```
def call_box(self ):
    self.contents = self.which_box.load()
    print(self.contents)
```

and you have to create `Box_Handler` objects, like this

```
Box_Handler(A).call_box()
Box_Handler(B).call_box()
```

with this fix the output becomes,

```
['banana,apple,pear', 'guava']
['orange,fig,grape', 'guava']
```

If you actually wanted to have list of fruits, you should be initializing the `contents` like this

```
self.contents = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear']    # list of strings
...
self.contents = ['orange', 'fig', 'grape']     # list of strings
```

and not like, how you have done in your program. Because,

```
self.contents = ['banana,apple,pear']   # list of a comma separated single string
```

With that change, the output becomes like this

```
['banana', 'apple', 'pear', 'guava']
['orange', 'fig', 'grape', 'guava']
```

Comment: This definitely answers the OP's question, but I feel like there is a deeply flawed design that is being overlooked.

Comment: @SethMMorton Oh, I see what you mean. Updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it indeed does work.
But why ? Isn't, 
self.contents = Box_B().load() 
the same as 
self.contents = self.which_box.load() ??

Comment: @NewbieGamer They both are different because `self.which_box` will refer to the already created object whereas `Box_B()` will create a new object. So, the changes you made to `B` will not be there in the newly created object.